# How to update a knockout view model based on a separate callback, rather than user input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have built a view model representing time slices with the following structure:

```
function TimeslotViewModel() {
    this.timeslots = ko.observableArray();

    this.updateTimeslots = function(timeslots) {
        this.timeslots.destroyAll();
    }

    this.clearTimeslots = function() {
        this.timeslots.destroyAll();
    }

    this.addTimeslot = function(timeslot) {
        this.timeslots.push(timeslot);
    }
}

function Timeslot(time, available) {
    this.time = time;
    this.available = available;
}
```

I'm trying to render this in a tabular format like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Time</th><th>Status</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: timeslots">
            <td data-bind="text: time"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: available"</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I've bound on page load:

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new TimeslotViewModel());
});
```

I'm trying to populate this table based on the callback result from an ajax call, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.  Here is what I tried:

```
$.getJSON(
          "/myAjaxCall",
          function (jsonData) {
              var timeslotViewModel = new TimeslotViewModel();
              timeslotViewModel.clearTimeslots();
              $.each(jsonData, function (i, ts) {
                  var tsData = JSON.parse(ts);
                  var timeslot = new Timeslot(tsData.time, tsData.booked);
                  timeslotViewModel.addTimeslot(timeslot);
              });
          });
```

Unfortunately, I'm not seeing my view model's array get populated at all from this code.  What is the right way to populate a view model based on a callback function's response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new viewmodel instead of updating the current one.

Replace this line

```
var timeslotViewModel = new TimeslotViewModel();
```

Either create a global viewmodel:

```
var myVm = new TimeslotViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myVm);

//...
var timeslotViewModel = myVm;
```

Or get the current one from a node:

```
var timeslotViewModel = ko.contextFor($('.container').get(0)).$root
```